# How can I programmatically change the selection of a google maps api autocomplete input?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I understand that in order to fire the place_changed event programmatically with the google maps javascript API v3 you do the following:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(autocomplete, 'place_changed');
```

However this simply fires the callback specified in the event and does not actually do anything to the `<input>` element that is attached.

What I need to do is programmatically change the selection in the autocomplete `<input>` to a specific location or place specified within the place object retrieved earlier via:

`autocomplete.getPlace()`

I can of course directly change the value in the input:

```
input.value = 'Whatever';
```

But doing this does not change the autocompletes selection.  After doing so the user has to delete the whole string in the `<input>`, and then finally begin typing again, in order to get the autocomplete predictions to show up again.

So to summarise I would like to change the **selection** of a google maps autocomplete input programmatically, using a place object obtained from the places/autocomplete api.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Presumably you need to trigger a keyboard event (keydown, keyup or keypress) on the input element after its value has been programmatically changed. This is easy with jQuery but can also be done in raw javascript - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events.

Answer (score 12):

If you have the `place` object you can do it via

```
autocomplete.set("place", place)
```

That will trigger the `place_changed` event in the autocomplete

Comment: will be great if you can provide the documentation to `set()` command

Comment: Here is the documentation for `set` - though it's entirely unhelpful - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCObject (Autocomplete extends `MVCObject` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete)

Comment: Related: if you have an address but don't have the `place` object, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892092/need-to-manually-start-the-google-places-autocomplete?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I don't know how I can get things done without SO.  Thanks!